# Tensorflow successfully installs on mac but gets ImportError on copyreg when used

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

After successfully `pip install`, importing the tensorflow library fails.

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 8, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/reflection.py", line 58, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import python_message as message_impl
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 59, in <module>
    import six.moves.copyreg as copyreg
ImportError: No module named copyreg
```

Comment: Have answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656551/unable-to-import-tensorflow/33691154#33691154

Comment: Why is this question closed as unclear?

Answer (score 21):

You can upgrade to six-1.10.x using

```
easy_install -U six
```

This will upgrade the current version of six from 1.4 to 1.10.x, that is required by tensorflow.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks @abhilash

Comment: @Mandy You are welcome!

Comment: Thank you. The upgrade worked for me. I also upgraded numpy too in the same way `easy_install -U numpy` because numpy version 1.9.2 or later was required.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: TensorFlow depends on protobuf which require six-1.10.0. Apple's default python environment has six-1.4.1 and may be difficult to upgrade. So we recommend either installing a separate copy of python via homebrew:

brew install python

or building / using TensorFlow within virtualenv as described above.

Comment: Upgrading six might not be that difficult. Try running `easy_install -U six` Up-to-date instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#on-macosx-)

Comment: thanks a lot, brew install python solved my problem

Comment: brew install python did it for me too

Answer (score 1):

`copyreg` is a `python3` function that is available in the `six` module in `python2.x`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html#module-copy_reg

To get `copyreg`, you have to install `six`:

```
pip install -U six
```

(Note: In `python2`, you access can either access the function with (i) `six.copy_reg` or when a module is imported with `six.moves.*`, it keeps the `python3` syntax, i.e. `six.moves.copyreg`)

Answer (score 0):

Since non of the suggested fixes worked for me, I changed the line

```
import six.moves.copyreg as copyreg
```

to

```
from six.moves import copyreg
```

and this seemed like this fixed this problem. However, I got another ImportError instead saying

```
dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Just posting this as an answer if someone else maybe has more success in this than me.